# New Files not showing in short-lived branch

Tags: sonarqube, branch

With sonarqube running on my project, I created a new branch other than main, as the default one and started working on the same. While running sonar, only the main(master) branch is taken into consideration by default. I tried this short-lived branch feature, but it compares the files with master branch and shows only the files which are modified in the new branch. The files which are created in the new branch are not shown. How to fix that ? or how to change the default branch in sonar.

Sonar : Community Edition : version 7.9

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the default branch in SonarQube, the community edition is seen to be showing all the projects as with 'master' branch.

Could refer https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/

> Master / Main Branch This is the default branch and typically
> corresponds to what's being developed for your next release. This is
> usually known within a development team as "master" or "head" and is
> analyzed when no specific branch parameters are provided. It is
> labeled "Main Branch" and defaults to the name "master" but can be
> renamed from the project settings at Administration > Branches and
> Pull Requests. **When you are using Community Edition, this is the
> only branch you see.**

Answer (score 0):

With community edition, I found a fix. Provide the value to `sonar.branch.name` to the intended branch. In my case `sonar.branch.name=sprint7_bugfixes`.  The sonar will run for whole of the branch and will update the content in dashboard, but still the name will be shown as master.

Another way of doing that is changing the project key and project name along with branch name.